# Flink:StreamingFileSink.withRollingPolicy doesn't work

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The rollover time i set is 5s,but it doesn't work.New file was created in 10s or 20s or 30s or more. I don't know why and how it work.The checkpoint time i set is 60s.

```
DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
.withRolloverInterval(5000)
.withInactivityInterval(5000)
.build())
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information?
What does it mean it does not work? You cannot see any files being committed or you have an exception? Also what do you mean "New file was created in 10s or 20s or 30s or more"?

A first thing to note is that files are going to be committed after the checkpoint is completed, so at least after the 60s.